# watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk-Conversation

Tags: android-studio, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

Hello I am referring [this](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk/blob/master/example/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/android/myapplication/MainActivity.java) Android sdk Watson Language Translation example and replacing with Conversation Service to deploy the application at Android Platform. At the sample code they have a class(image below) at MainActivity.java. How do I make the necessary changes in syntax format for Conversation Service of this particular class? Please help. 
[image]

Comment: Take a aook at the https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk there are examples for the conversation service that you can use in your `MainActivity`

Comment: I am using this https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/blob/master/examples/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/conversation/v1/ConversationExample.java async way to do API call. The API call is happening but i don't see any dialog flow of the conversation at my phone UI. why is that so?

Comment: There could be 123123 problems. I would suggest you spend more time trying to debug your app

Comment: I am trying, but i only see my TextView string on my Android UI.

Comment: But i have a doubt, in https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/blob/master/examples/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/conversation/v1/ConversationExample.java this sample, we are no where linking the R.id of the TextView or EditText or Button of android platform in the `MainActivity.java` file. Is that why I don't see my dialog flow?

Comment: I could see my conversation JSON at my console as i used System.out.println(output) at my code of Android Studio. I see I need to extract the JSON file to Java object and parse. Is there a sample code already on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ConversationService conversationService = new ConversationService(ConversationService.VERSION_DATE_2016_07_11, userName, password);
MessageRequest.Builder messageRequestBuilder = new MessageRequest.Builder();
messageRequestBuilder.inputText(question);
ServiceCall<MessageResponse> response = conversationService.message(workspaceId, messageRequestBuilder.build());
MessageResponse answer =  response.execute();
```

Comment: Thanks :) it was helpful.